# Can you recall the author and name of a baroque Passacaille or Chaconne which uses both the descending and the ascending tetrachord in the bass?

Tags: baroque-period

I happened to listen to a baroque passacaille or chaconne for strings on the air.
It used both the descending and the ascending tetrachord in the ostinato bass.
I wasn't able to find anything on the web.
Can you recall the author and name of the piece ?
Thank you ! :)

Comment: Hi Claudi - welcome. That type of question is not on topic here.

Comment: You might try [MusicFans.SE].